# Random Color Background

Tags: java, swing, graphics, keylistener, paintcomponent

I am trying to get this code to change the background color to a random color when I press 'r'. So far everything is working ok other than changing the background color to a random color. This program is a screen saver that I have to generate random shapes in random positions with random colors.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class ScreenSaver1 extends JPanel {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("FullSize");
    private Rectangle rectangle;
    boolean full;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    ScreenSaver1() {
        // Remove the title bar, min, max, close stuff
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        // Add a Key Listener to the frame
        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
        // Add this panel object to the frame
        frame.add(this);
        // Get the dimensions of the screen
        rectangle = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
        .getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
        // Set the size of the frame to the size of the screen
        frame.setSize(rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        // Remember that we are currently at full size
        full = true;
    }

// This method will run when any key is pressed in the window
class KeyHandler extends KeyAdapter {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // Terminate the program.
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'x') {
            System.out.println("Exiting");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if (e.getKeyChar() == 'r') {
            System.out.println("Change background color");
            setBackground(new Color((int)Math.random() * 256, (int)Math.random() * 256, (int)Math.random() * 256));
        }
        else if (e.getKeyChar() == 'z') {
            System.out.println("Resizing");
            frame.setSize((int)rectangle.getWidth() / 2, (int)rectangle.getHeight());
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScreenSaver1 obj = new ScreenSaver1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start by removing `setBackground(Color.BLACK);` from your `paintComponent` method

The other problem you're having is with the way you are calculating your random values...

```
(int)Math.random() * 256
```

This is basically casting the result of `Math.random()` to an `int`, which will, typically, result in it becoming `0`, before it's multiplied by `256`, which is `0`...

Instead, try using something like

```
(int)(Math.random() * 256)
```

Which will perform the calculation of `Math.random() * 256` before casting the result to `int`

You may also want to take a look at [`Frame#getExtendedState`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#getExtendedState%28%29) and [`Frame#setExtendedState`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState%28int%29)...it will make your life considerably eaiser...

Comment: I forgot repaint(). I was just using setBackground(Color.BLACK)as a test. also when I do that it only changes from white to black.

Comment: that also makes sense. That is why it was becoming black.

Comment: @Ryel, repaint() is not necessary. Swing is smart enough to do a repaint() when a component property changes. -1 for the repaint() suggestion. +1 for the other two suggestions.

Comment: @camickr You win some, you lose some

Comment: Also consider `Color.getHSBColor(r.nextFloat(), 1, 1)`, where `r` is an instance of `Random`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(int)(Math.random() * 256)
```

Or this:

```
Random gen= new Random();
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.Black);
```

To get random colors, try this:

```
.setBackground(Color.(gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256),
                gen.nextInt(256));
```

Comment: Please consider formatting you answer, it was not completely readable for me.